# Sending an email with attachment

Tags: python, python-3.x, email

I am trying to write a function that send an email with an attached file. At the moment, it send an email but without attachment. Can you someone comment?

```
    msg = MIMEMultipart()

    msg['From'] = my email

    msg['To'] = client email address

    msg['Subject'] = subject

    body = content

    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
    ##### Load the address of the file which should be attached*********************************     
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("Text 
    files","*.txt"),("all files","*.*")))     

    Myfile = open(filename)

    attachment = MIMEText(Myfile.read())
    attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)           


    msg.attach(attachment)
    mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    msg = f'Subject: {subject}\n\n{content}'
    mail.ehlo()
    mail.starttls()
    mail.login('My email address', 'password')
    mail.sendmail('client email', My email address, msg)
    mail.close()
```

Thank you all in advance

Comment: "Can you someone comment?" - sure, here I am, commenting on your post! What's the actual issue you're facing?

Comment: You're overwriting `msg` here: `msg = f'Subject: {subject}\n\n{content}'`, so you're sending only this string, not the object created here: `msg = MIMEMultipart()`

Comment: Thanks, I tried to get ride of "msg = f'Subject: {subject}\n\n{content}" but started throwing other errors such as "  return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object"

Answer (score 0):

First, as mentioned in my comment, you're overwriting `msg` here:

```
msg = f'Subject: {subject}\n\n{content}'
```

At this point, the `MIMEMultipart` object `msg` used to point to is destroyed, and you'll send only that new string. No wonder why there's no attachment: this string obviously doesn't have an attachment.

Now, you should really be using the new API of the `email` module, as shown [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/email.examples.html). But since you're already using the legacy API (the `MIMEMultipart` class, for example), you'll need to convert `msg` to a string, as shown [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/email-examples.html):

```
# This is copied straight from the last link

msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = "Link"
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you

...

part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')  # example attachment

# Attach parts into message container.
# According to RFC 2046, the last part of a multipart message, in this case
# the HTML message, is best and preferred.
msg.attach(part1)

mail.sendmail(
    me, you,
    msg.as_string()  # CONVERT TO STRING
)
```